# javascript string encoding on client

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding

I have the following problem

I get a list of string on my client encoded like

```
users = ['B1', 'B2', 'Bo\xc5\xbei\xc4\x87', ...]
```

list comes from web2py server (i tried to convert strings there, no luck at all)

once it is presented to user in browser the Bo\xc5\xbei\xc4\x87 becomes

```
BoÅ¾iÄ
```

it works the same on Chrome, mozila, etc.

any suggestions how to solve the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to **escape** it

```
users = ['B1', 'B2', 'Bo\\xc5\\xbei\\xc4\\x87'];
```

Comment: please tell me how. Any solution is ok. BTW result should be Božič

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using response.json(object) in my view

```
{{=XML(response.json(object))}};
```